# Server root always shows Welcome to Nginx

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, nginx, octobercms

I’m using [OctoberCMS](http://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#nginx-configuration) and have installed Nginx using apt-get on my Ubuntu 14.04 instance in IBM Softlayer. This is my configuration and for some reason I’m finding strange behaviour. I have worked with linux and have installed nginx before but this has got annoying.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/hd;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    rewrite ^themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm /index.php break;
    rewrite ^bootstrap/.* /index.php break;
    rewrite ^config/.* /index.php break;
    rewrite ^vendor/.* /index.php break;
    rewrite ^storage/cms/.* /index.php break;
    rewrite ^storage/logs/.* /index.php break;
    rewrite ^storage/framework/.* /index.php break;
    rewrite ^storage/temp/protected/.* /index.php break;
    rewrite ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* /index.php break;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The issue is that my root http://mywebsite.com/ shows the infamous “Welcome to nginx!” page but http://mywebsite.com/index.php shows my actual web app frontpage. I have tried searching stackoverflow for similar issues and tested various responses but in vain. What is more surprising is that when I did a clean uninstall of nginx i.e. by doing a apt-get purge and delete nginx it removed my web app but still displays that Welcome page which is surprising (even after rm -rf /etc/nginx) so I’m confused on what is happening here. Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your index is not set to `index.php`...

Comment: I did set it. And still it showed the same error. Surprisingly, after 2 days it started working. I think it has something to do with some caching that was going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is to do with your PHP location block. Try updating your location blocks to the below configuration. *This is designed for PHP 7, as Laravel no long supports PHP 5*

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```